# Kubernetes: horizontal auto-scaling based on metrics in another namespace

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, prometheus, ingress

I'd like to set up horizontal auto-scaling for a deployment based on the metrics of the ingress-controller deployed in another namespace.

I have a deployment (`petclinic`) deployed in a certain namespace (`petclinic`).

I have an ingress controller (`nginx-ingress`) deployed in another namespace (`nginx-ingress`).

The ingress controller has been deployed with Helm and Tiller, so I have the following `ServiceMonitor` entity:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"monitoring.coreos.com/v1","kind":"ServiceMonitor","metadata":{"annotations":{},"creationTimestamp":"2019-08-19T10:48:00Z","generation":5,"labels":{"app":"nginx-ingress","chart":"nginx-ingress-1.12.1","component":"controller","heritage":"Tiller","release":"nginx-ingress"},"name":"nginx-ingress-controller","namespace":"nginx-ingress","resourceVersion":"7391237","selfLink":"/apis/monitoring.coreos.com/v1/namespaces/nginx-ingress/servicemonitors/nginx-ingress-controller","uid":"0217c466-5b78-4e38-885a-9ee65deb2dcd"},"spec":{"endpoints":[{"interval":"30s","port":"metrics"}],"namespaceSelector":{"matchNames":["nginx-ingress"]},"selector":{"matchLabels":{"app":"nginx-ingress","component":"controller","release":"nginx-ingress"}}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2019-08-21T13:12:00Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
    chart: nginx-ingress-1.12.1
    component: controller
    heritage: Tiller
    release: nginx-ingress
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: nginx-ingress
  resourceVersion: "7663160"
  selfLink: /apis/monitoring.coreos.com/v1/namespaces/nginx-ingress/servicemonitors/nginx-ingress-controller
  uid: 33421be7-108b-4b81-9673-05db140364ce
spec:
  endpoints:
  - interval: 30s
    port: metrics
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
    - nginx-ingress
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-ingress
      component: controller
      release: nginx-ingress
```

I also have the Prometheus Operaton instance, it has found this entity and it has updated the Prometheus' configuration with this stanza:

```
- job_name: nginx-ingress/nginx-ingress-controller/0
  honor_labels: false
  kubernetes_sd_configs:
  - role: endpoints
    namespaces:
      names:
      - nginx-ingress
  scrape_interval: 30s
  relabel_configs:
  - action: keep
    source_labels:
    - __meta_kubernetes_service_label_app
    regex: nginx-ingress
  - action: keep
    source_labels:
    - __meta_kubernetes_service_label_component
    regex: controller
  - action: keep
    source_labels:
    - __meta_kubernetes_service_label_release
    regex: nginx-ingress
  - action: keep
    source_labels:
    - __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name
    regex: metrics
  - source_labels:
    - __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_kind
    - __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_name
    separator: ;
    regex: Node;(.*)
    replacement: ${1}
    target_label: node
  - source_labels:
    - __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_kind
    - __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_name
    separator: ;
    regex: Pod;(.*)
    replacement: ${1}
    target_label: pod
  - source_labels:
    - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
    target_label: namespace
  - source_labels:
    - __meta_kubernetes_service_name
    target_label: service
  - source_labels:
    - __meta_kubernetes_pod_name
    target_label: pod
  - source_labels:
    - __meta_kubernetes_service_name
    target_label: job
    replacement: ${1}
  - target_label: endpoint
    replacement: metrics
```

I also have a Prometheus-Adapter instance, so I have the `custom.metrics.k8s.io` API in the list of available APIs.

The metrics are being collected and exposed, so the following command:

```
$ kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/nginx-ingress/ingresses/petclinic/nginx_ingress_controller_requests" | jq .
```

gives the following result:

```
{
  "kind": "MetricValueList",
  "apiVersion": "custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "selfLink": "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/nginx-ingress/ingresses/petclinic/nginx_ingress_controller_requests"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "describedObject": {
        "kind": "Ingress",
        "namespace": "nginx-ingress",
        "name": "petclinic",
        "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1"
      },
      "metricName": "nginx_ingress_controller_requests",
      "timestamp": "2019-08-20T12:56:50Z",
      "value": "11"
    }
  ]
}
```

So far so good, right?

And what I need is to set up the HPA entity for my deployment. Doing something like that:

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: petclinic
  namespace: petclinic
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: petclinic
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
  - type: Object
    object:
      metricName: nginx_ingress_controller_requests
      target:
        apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
        kind: Ingress
        name: petclinic
      targetValue: 10k
```

Of course, this is incorrect, as the `nginx_ingress_controller_requests` is related to the `nginx-ingress` namespace, so it doesn't work (well, as it was expected):

```
    annotations:
      autoscaling.alpha.kubernetes.io/conditions: '[{"type":"AbleToScale","status":"True","lastTransitionTime":"2019-08-19T18:43:42Z","reason":"SucceededGetScale","message":"the
        HPA controller was able to get the target''s current scale"},{"type":"ScalingActive","status":"False","lastTransitionTime":"2019-08-19T18:55:26Z","reason":"FailedGetObjectMetric","message":"the
        HPA was unable to compute the replica count: unable to get metric nginx_ingress_controller_requests:
        Ingress on petclinic petclinic/unable to fetch metrics
        from custom metrics API: the server could not find the metric nginx_ingress_controller_requests
        for ingresses.extensions petclinic"},{"type":"ScalingLimited","status":"False","lastTransitionTime":"2019-08-19T18:43:42Z","reason":"DesiredWithinRange","message":"the
        desired count is within the acceptable range"}]'
      autoscaling.alpha.kubernetes.io/current-metrics: '[{"type":""},{"type":"Resource","resource":{"name":"cpu","currentAverageUtilization":1,"currentAverageValue":"10m"}}]'
      autoscaling.alpha.kubernetes.io/metrics: '[{"type":"Object","object":{"target":{"kind":"Ingress","name":"petclinic","apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1"},"metricName":"nginx_ingress_controller_requests","targetValue":"10k"}}]'
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"autoscaling/v2beta1","kind":"HorizontalPodAutoscaler","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"petclinic","namespace":"petclinic"},"spec":{"maxReplicas":10,"metrics":[{"object":{"metricName":"nginx_ingress_controller_requests","target":{"apiVersion":"extensions/v1beta1","kind":"Ingress","name":"petclinic"},"targetValue":"10k"},"type":"Object"}],"minReplicas":1,"scaleTargetRef":{"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"Deployment","name":"petclinic"}}}
```

And here's what I see in the log-file of Prometheus-Adapter:

```
I0820 15:42:13.467236       1 wrap.go:42] GET /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/petclinic/ingresses.extensions/petclinic/nginx_ingress_controller_requests: (6.124398ms) 404 [[kube-controller-manager/v1.15.1 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/4485c6f/system:serviceaccount:kube-system:horizontal-pod-autoscaler] 10.103.98.0:37940]
```

HPA looks for this metric in the deployment's namespace, but I need it to fetch it from the `nginx-ingress` namespace, just like so:

```
I0820 15:44:40.044797       1 wrap.go:42] GET /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/nginx-ingress/ingresses/petclinic/nginx_ingress_controller_requests: (2.210282ms) 200 [[kubectl/v1.15.2 (linux/amd64) kubernetes/f627830] 10.103.97.0:35142]
```

Alas, the `autoscaling/v2beta1` API doesn't have the `spec.metrics.object.target.namespace` entity, so I can't "ask" it to fetch the value from another namespace. :-(

Would anyone be so kind as to help me to solve this puzzle? Is there a way to set up auto-scaling based on the custom metrics that belong to another namespace?

Maybe there's the way to make this metric available in the same namespace to which this ingress.extension belongs?

Thanks in advance for any clues and tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I've figured it out. Here's the part of the prometheus-adapter configuration I needed:

```
    rules:
    - seriesQuery: '{__name__=~"^nginx_ingress_.*",namespace!=""}'
      seriesFilters: []
      resources:
        template: <<.Resource>>
        overrides:
          exported_namespace:
            resource: "namespace"
      name:
        matches: ""
        as: ""
      metricsQuery: sum(<<.Series>>{<<.LabelMatchers>>}) by (<<.GroupBy>>)
```

Ta-da! :-)

Comment: This dives me nut! confirm worked.

Comment: @Volodymyr can you please elaborate on this solution a little? I also have a similar usecase in which there is a pod in namespace A which triggers a metric that I want to use in a HPA defined for autoscaling pods in namespace B.

Comment: @avin, that's not easy to remember, as it was more than 3 years ago. :-) The point was that I've added a rule for prometheus-adapter and fetched the values as from an arbitrary prometheus metric which is not bound to any namespace.

Answer (score 0):

My choice would be to export an external metric from prometheus, as those are not namespace dependent.

@Volodymyr Melnyk You need prometheus adapter to export the custom metric to the petclinic namespace, and I don't see that being solved in your config, maybe you also made other configurations you forgot to mention?